# I want to create a `collection` in `Isar`, but I'm encountering a completely puzzling error and having trouble

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-freezed, flutter-isar

I want to create a collection like the following, but when I run flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs, I get the following error.

```dart
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';

part 'model.freezed.dart';
part 'model.g.dart';

@freezed
@Collection(ignore: {'copyWith'}, inheritance: false)
class Model with _$Model {
  const factory Model({
    required String address,
  }) = _Model;
  Id get id => Isar.autoIncrement;
  const Model._();
}
```

error:

```
Constructor parameter does not match a property.
|
| required String address,
|
```

Despite having a simple collection, I'm encountering an error and struggling. How can I resolve this error?

Additionally, while the freezed files are being generated, the `.g.` files for `Isar` are not being created.

Comment: Can you show the generated code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I'm posting this question because it doesn't generate.

Comment: @sub What is your Isar version? Isar version is very important to understand your code, because ISAR v4 has several breakings.

Answer (score 0):

When I remove the part `inheritance: false,` the `.g.` files are created without any issues.